# Setting className of redux container component

Tags: css, reactjs, redux

Simple question, I want to set the className of the div created by using connect for styling purposes. I've tried just setting

```
<Container className='test' />
```

on the container component but the class is not assigned to the div rendered on the page. How can I add a class to a container so I can target it with css?

Comment: It is a duplicate in the sense that className is passed as prop to the Component similar to what happens to onClick in the duplicate question. The solution is the same

Comment: You have to set the className to the `div`. Since your passing `className` as prop to `container` and if your `div` is inside the `render` of `container` then use something like this on div `<div className={this.props.className} />